# qt5 (and python) - How to get the default thumbnail size of user's os

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, thumbnails, pyside

I am looking to create an image browser that shows nicely and evenly tiled thumbnails, on a native looking file browser.

On windows, I'm hoping it would look something similar to this:

[image]

On ubuntu, I'm hoping it would look something similar to this:

[image]

But this is what's available right now:

[image: thumbnail sized are different from default size]

One of the issues I'm facing involves specifying the correct thumbnail size for the images. I understand that I can set the thumbnail size programatically by using the code `self.setIconSize(QSize(32, 32))`, however, setting the thumbnail size this way may result in sizes inconsistent with the system default, making it look unnatural.

**So my question is:** How do I get the "default thumbnail size" that is set on the user's desktop, to make my thumbnail appearance consistent with the user's os (using qt5 or more specifically PySide2 or PyQt5)?

Here's the code I'm working with so far:
`

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import QSize
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QMainWindow

class ThumbsWindow(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setViewMode(QListWidget.IconMode)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(32, 32))

        myimage_path = "./images/web.png"
        myimage_path1 = "./images/image1.jpg"
        myimage_path2 = "./images/image2.jpg"
        myimage_path3 = "./images/image3.jpg"

        image_list = [myimage_path, myimage_path1, myimage_path2, myimage_path3]
        # create a list of QIcons
        image_items = [QListWidgetItem(QIcon(path_x), "sample image") for path_x in image_list]

        # add each of the QIcons onto the QListWidget
        for image_item in image_items:
            self.addItem(image_item)


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        t = ThumbsWindow()
        self.setCentralWidget(t)

        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Image Thumbnails')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`

Comment: What makes you think there is a default system size? I don't see any evidence for that in your question. And in any case, why can't you just let the user choose the size for themselves (which is probably what all the other applications do)?

Comment: An example would be an ubuntu user, when opening his "Pictures" folder, is met with thumbnailed versions of whatever pictures are in that folder. He is presented with a uniform _default_ size for these thumbails. Ubuntu does not pop open a dialog box that requires the user to enter what size he wants his thumbnails to be, before he is shown the thumbnailed contents of his folder.

Same thing with windows users. Windows users are presented with thumbnails that have a _uniform_ default size, even without first asking the user to specify what he wants the size of his thumbnails to be.

Comment: But that doesn't show that there's a default **system** size. Each application just does its own thing.

Comment: PS: in the file manager I use ([dolphin](http://www.kde.org/applications/system/dolphin/)), there's a slider in the status bar that adjusts the size of icons and previews. There's also a section in the settings for configuring the default sizes.

Comment: I understand that it's possible in certain OSs to modify the thumbnail/icon sizes later on. But what I'm looking for is the system wide default size used to display these thumbnails, even before the user specifies his preferred size (for that particular folder or otherwise).

I am simply attempting to make the size of the thumbnails and icons in the application I'm making consistent with whichever size is currently used by the system as a whole. Or maybe to clarify, I'm looking for a way to determine which size the OSs file browser uses as its default thumbnail size.

Comment: I refer you to my first comment ;-) Perhaps you should take the time to verify that such a system-wide default exists on all the platforms you wish to support - otherwise it's just a wild-goose chase, no? Personally, I would just: (1) pick a size, any size, (2) allow the user to adjust things to their own liking.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, however, I honestly don't see how verifying something so self evident would help in solving this issue. I've already provided an example, and the images I posted also show what I'm trying to achieve.  Furthermore, a simple google search for the term "windows default thumbnail size" and "ubuntu default thumbnail size" show how the default thumbnail sizes of these OSs can be changed to something else, showing that there is such a thing as a default system value for thumbnails. I just want to know how to get that value using Qt.

Comment: I do see the value in just taking the shortcut of arbitrarily choosing "a value, any value", just to get it over with, however this would cause thumbnails to look off kilter and unnatural to the user. Of course it would still be best to provide a means for the user to choose a different size for his thumbnails, however I would also want to provide the means to revert thumbnail sizes to the size he has set on his OS.

Comment: I see no evidence at all that there is a system-wide default on either windows or ubuntu. There are certainly *application-specific* defaults for windows explorer and nautilus, and you can probably get those values from the windows registry and dconf, respectively. But what if your user prefers a different file-manager (there are many others available, especially on linux)? You'll first need to determine the default file-manager (if that's even possible), and then write a whole load of conditional code to get the default icon sizes (depending on the platform, version, etc). Not much fun.

Comment: " I just want to know how to get that value using Qt." Maybe it's just not possible with Qt alone.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm probably a little late to help by answering this, but I believe you are looking at this from the wrong approach.
As others have said there is not technically a "system default" size for image thumbnails.  The thumbnails are displayed on a file manager program (Windows Explorer, Nautilus, etc.) which is what dictates the size of the thumbnails. Not the system.

Both of the programs above give the user the ability to adjust the size of the thumbnails, so even if there was a default system setting, one users preferred size would not be universal.

What you may want to do is open the default file manager beside your GUI and compare the icon sizes.  If yours is smaller than the default file manager, adjust icon size in your code (the way you posted above) and compare again.  When they look close enough to the same size to suite you, that's your default size.  If you want to give the user the option to adjust the size, add the options in to adjust it and then save the new size as the icon size that is initialized when the application is started, allowing the user to choose their own default size.

Aside from this I don't believe there is a way to pull the icon size from the default file manager.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. You're right. I ended up using a solution similar to what you said. But instead of slowly comparing icon size with the default GUI's, then readjusting step by step, I decided to use the preset values found here instead: http://www.visualpharm.com/articles/icon_sizes.html . Basically, when the user opens up the app, icon sizes are set to 48 x 48 for windows and linux. After which, the user can adjust icon sizes based on the different sizes enumerated in the above link.